# How to resolve react js installation error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

hello everyone i want to install react js into my system for learning but i am unable to install react.
Here are the steps that i have followed to install the react app.

1. At first i have downloaded the LTS version of node js.
2. Then i have installed node js into my C-Drive.
3. To check whether the node js has successfully installed or not i have used the command `npm -v` and `node -v`.
4. And I found out them as `v6.14.4` and `v12.16.3` respectively.
5. Now to install react globally i have used `npm install -g create-react-app` into my C-Drive
6. To check whether `create-react-app` installed i have used `create-react-app --version`.
7. And it shown me `3.4.1`
8. Now i have used `create-react-app reactapp` into a folder react in E-Drive
9. But i am facing an error it is saying

```
e:\react-learn>create-react-app reactapp

Creating a new React app in e:\react-learn\reactapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-templa


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall e:\react-learn\reactapp\node_modu
node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall e:\react-learn\reactapp\node_modul
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall e:\react-learn\reactapp\node_
re
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ react@16.13.1
+ cra-template@1.0.3
added 1616 packages from 751 contributors and audited 1620 pac


59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

it's been an hour, but after this the codes are not running, so what i need to do next please suggest me.
I have tried these steps too...

1. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088
2. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8097

but still from these parts

````
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details```
````

the codes are not moving forward what kind of problem it is and how can i solve it???

Answer (score 0):

as it suggests run npm audit fix on the terminal but the react app is already created and you just "cd reactP" into the folder and start working

try the following steps

1. npm rm -g create-react-app
2. npm install -g create-react-app
3. npx create-react-app my-app

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088

Comment: but the src and public folders are not there

Comment: then there is some more error can you post entire  log after running  create-react-app reactp

Comment: I suggest you to delete the reactp folder and re run the "create-react-app reactp"

Comment: i have done that once but same problem see i have edited

Comment: sure `node_modules folder, package.json and package-lock.json`

Comment: Its not working i am pasting what is there in package.json

Comment: `{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}`

Comment: try running npm rm -g create-react-app.  
npm install -g create-react-app. 
npx create-react-app my-app.

Comment: i dont understand. Do you mean these are the steps to follow one by one?

Comment: check my answer again i have edited it and let me know once  you run those cmds

Comment: Okay i will let you know

Comment: No, the same issue its not working for me maybe there is an another issue, i am trying with yarn lets see

Comment: i have tried 4-5 steps more but the result is same `added 1616 packages from 751 contributors and audited 1620 pac


59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details` after this codes are not running forward